# Javascript closure and scope riddle

Tags: javascript

I'v heard this question, and I'm unsure as how to solve it.

The requirement is: implement the function `from` so it will preform like so on the following scenario:

```
var x = from(3);
console.log(x()); //outputs 3
console.log(x()); //outputs 4
//TODO: implement from()
```

I tried something like:

```
function from(val) {
  var counter = val;
  return function(){
    return counter+=1;
  }
}
```

But the first time I run it, it increments the value, So that's a no go.

Comment: Have you tried to implement it at all yet?

Comment: So, what went wrong with your implementation?

Comment: did you try something out yourself?

Comment: Post-increment will do the trick, instead of returning `counter+=1` return `counter++`, that way `counter` is first returned, then incremented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = from(3);

function from(startValue) {
   var counter = startValue;
   return function() {
     return counter++;
   }
}

console.log(x()); //outputs 3
console.log(x()); //outputs 4
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution would be to simply subtract `1` from `counter`:

```
function from(val) {
    var counter = val - 1;
    return function(){
        return counter += 1;
    }
}
```

However, in this case you can make use of the postfix `++` operator, because in `counter++`, the value of `counter` is increased by one, but the **old** value of `counter` is returned.
You should be good to go with

```
function from(val) {
    var counter = val;
    return function(){
        return counter++;
    }
}
```

For completeness, the equivalent to `counter += 1` would be `++counter`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function from(val) {
  var counter = val;
  return function() {
    return counter++;
  }
}

var x = from(3);
alert(x()); //outputs 3
alert(x()); //outputs 4
alert(x()); //outputs 5
alert(x()); //outputs 6
alert(x()); //outputs 7
alert(x()); //outputs 8
```

Try this